# How not to make refresh pages in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

### Issue

I'm using a `ViewPager` with `fragment`s.
Every fragment has a `button` in its layout which, when clicked, should **run** a piece of **code** and then **disappear**.

If I click a button, it runs the code and disappears as programmed.

But if I swap away from that fragment of 2 tabs, and then I get back to it, it looks like the ViewPager killed the cache for that fragment and restored it with its default layout: so the button appears again.

How can I always keep saved the status of each fragment? I don't want the ViewPager to keep saved just the two fragments asides the one I'm looking at.

---

### Images

### [image] [image] [image] [image]

### Adapter

Here's my adapter:

```
public class MineAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public MineAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    //Fill Data directly from Repository
    return CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getListOfLavels().size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((FrameLayout) object);
}

@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    System.out.println("Code executed");

    final View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.carousal_page, container,
            false);

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.iron);
            break;
        case 1:
            itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.coal);
            break;
        case 2:
            itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gold);
            break;
    }

    //Mine Name
    ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mineName)).setText(
            CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getListOfLavels().get(position).getmName());

    //Mine Cost
    ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mineCost)).setText("" +
            CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getListOfLavels().get(position).getUnlockCost());

    //Mine Cost
    ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mineDropRate)).setText("" +
            CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getListOfLavels().get(position).getDropRate());

    //Mineral Name
    ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mineMineral)).setText(
            CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getListOfLavels().get(position).getMineral().getName());

    //Mineral Drop Rate
    ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mineDropRate)).setText("" +
            CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getListOfLavels().get(position).getMineral().getValue());

    // Unlock Button
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.unlockButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getCurrentUser().getGold() >=
                    CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getListOfLavels().get(position).getUnlockCost()) {

                //If User has more gold than cost to unlock remove lock image and buy it

                CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getCurrentUser().setGold(
                        CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getCurrentUser().getGold()
                                - CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getListOfLavels().get(position).getUnlockCost()); // Update user's gold


                itemView.findViewById(R.id.unlockButton).setVisibility(View.GONE); // Remove lock button


                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        "Reduced " + CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getListOfLavels().get(position).getUnlockCost() +
                                "\n Updated Gold " + CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance()
                                .getCurrentUser().getGold(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                // Not enough money
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Not enough money to purchase You need " +
                        (CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getListOfLavels().get(position).getUnlockCost()
                                - CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance().getCurrentUser().getGold()) + "More", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    container.addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((FrameLayout) object);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)
```

is what you need in for ViewPager view.

[Android developer link for ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

Comment: Where should I write this?

Comment: ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager) 
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit( <total number of fragments/2> )

Comment: I tried this, still not working: viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3/2);

Comment: thats 3/2 is 1 in computer science. if you have total 4 pages, make the limit to 2.

2 will be on either side will be preserved. so 2 on left, your current page, 2 on right. here maximum  of 5 pages can be preserved. same if argument is 3, total 7 pages are preserved and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Save the state of the button's visibility in onSaveInstanceState and handle it accordingly in onViewCreated.

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    btnTest = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
    btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btnTest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        btnTest.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("button_visibility",View.VISIBLE));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("button_visibility",btnTest.getVisibility());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```